# do we have structure "try yourself + adj"?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-structure

I heard people said "**don't try yourself so crazy**" in the movie "Almost Christmas".

I am not sure I misheard it.

Bu no dictionary says about "**try yourself + adj**".

do we have structure "**try yourself + adj**"?

**please refer a resource to your answer!**

Comment: You've misheard: the line is "Don't **drive** yourself too crazy with it".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a misheard conversation.